# How to upsert many in Mongo + Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

Everyday, I have a 500mb file that I need parse and save to the db.

When the db is clear, `insert_many` works for me.

```
Device.collection.insert_many(devices, ordered=false)
```

- `devices` is an array:

```
[ {id:"111", type:"aaa"},
  {id:"222", type:"bbb"},
  {id:"333", type:"ccc"} ]
```

However, some of the types in the array could change daily. And the array length could also change.

Question, how do I do a upsert_many with Mongoid? If id match, update if needed. If id not found, save the new document.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell the most efficient way of doing this is through the driver's bulk write API.

Use `update_one` with `upsert: true`: https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/master/tutorials/ruby-driver-bulk-operations/#update-one

Given your `devices` array, I would `map` each element to a bulk write operation which finds by the `id` in the array element and sets the attributes, with `upsert: true`. Then feed these bulk operations to `Collection#bulk_write`. You may need to split the entire `devices` array into chunks to stay under the 16 MB limit for BSON documents or for performance reasons.

Comment: Is there a reason you pick `update_one` and not `update_many`?

Comment: You said: 

>  If id match, update if needed. If id not found, save the new document.

There should be at most one document for a given id.